# How to properly align controls in Android view?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Ok this is really frustrating me and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have a RelativeLayout in one of my views and I have an image view which is a circle, I have two buttons, each are semi circles about 1/3 of the image circle. I want to align these buttons so they are at the top and bottom third of the circle img. The graphical layout keeps snapping them in random places, nowhere near where I want them to be...how do I do this properly?

Here is what my view looks like, I tried clicking around on everything and I can't seem to align them properly. I would really appreciate a link or someone to explain how you would go about creating similar buttons...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
android:layout_margin="0dp"
android:background="#404a5b"
android:keepScreenOn="true"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/timerValue"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="30dp"
        android:paddingTop="30dp"
        android:text="@string/timerVal"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="40sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imgElipse"
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="350dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
        android:src="@drawable/mainscreen_ellipse" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnStopTrip"
        style="@style/ButtonText"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgElipse"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_margin="0dp"
        android:background="@drawable/stop_button"
        android:padding="50dp"
        android:paddingBottom="0dp"
        android:text="@string/stopTrip"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textSize="14sp" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of padding try using margin property. this property will help in proper alignment.

```
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"
```

Comment: Doesn't do it for me :(, tried the padding and margin, and the button doesn't even budge. If I drag it I can either place it where it is now or above the imgview.

Comment: okay.  try reducing the width and height of the image view it looks too large

Comment: try removing this from your page before moving them.

      android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"

Answer (score 0):

You can try using vertical linear layout...

ps: you said you have 2 buttons,but xml code shows only 1 button...

Comment: Yeah, after the trouble aligning one, I delete the other one until the first one is properly aligned. I will try the vertical linear layout now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

remove the android property and then align

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

Comment: Removed and still the same, even resizing it does not take any effect. it is whatever size it is and I can't seem to mess with the button :(

Comment: The button ALWAYS snaps to the bottom of the circle ImageView. I can't move it up or down from there unless it snaps to the bottom or the top of screen/view.